# Production ready SQL Server transport for NServiceBus?

Tags: sql-server, nservicebus

Is there a productionready SQL Server transport for NServiceBus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the next major release (v4) of NServiceBus we have a SqlServer transport out of the box.

We will be starting beta releases of v4 very soon but in the meantime if you want to get your feet wet, you can d/l a pre-release version from nuget https://nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus.SqlServer and give that a go for evaluation purposes.

Comment: Thank you! But I need it now...as usual. ;)

Comment: Hey John--is there a list of confirmed features for v4 available?

Comment: The best is to have a look in GitHub, https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues?milestone=26&page=1&state=closed

Comment: @eric-z the v4 version is quite stable, so I guess you could start using it today in your development environment